# Issue with sample() in R

Tags: r, sample

Pretty simple question. I am trying to sample 20 numbers (with replacement) from the first 10 natural numbers.

This

```
sample(x = 1:10, size = 0.2*100, replace = TRUE) %>% length
```

gives `20` (and works), but

```
sample(x = 1:10, size = (1-0.8)*100, replace = TRUE) %>% length
```

gives `19`.

I can always do

```
sample(x = 1:10, size = (100 - 0.8*100), replace = TRUE) %>% length
```

(that works fine and shows `20`), but I'm curious why having it in parenthesis doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It is because the value is not exactly equal to 20 in size.  We can either round or use ceiling

```
sample(x = 1:10, size = ceiling((1-0.8)*100), replace = TRUE) %>% length
#[1] 20
```

---

```
20 - (1-0.8)*100
#[1] 3.552714e-15
```

Comment: I understand, but I need to be able get `20` when I pass `0.8` and `19` when I pass `0.81`

Comment: @wrahool these are floating point and there is precision involved in it.  So, it is not going to be an exact value

Comment: wouldn't round be better than ceiling in this case?

Comment: Please read FAQ 7.31.  This will help answer you questions about floating point numbers.